# Cleanest way to store these values in a mongo db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am adding a series of user_ids to a mongo db document, each of them has a number associated with them between 1 and 9.  But it is not necessary sequential.  So does it make more sense to add this to my document:

```
{"4" => "user_id1", "7" => "user_id2"}
```

or

`[nil, nil, nil, "user_id1", nil, nil, "user_id2"]`
(knowing that there is an offset)

My feeling is that using a hash is quicker in terms of resources and access times, but using an array is cleaner and makes more logical sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *using an array is cleaner and makes more logical sense* then you should use an array.

You only have nine entries so any space savings will be irrelevant unless you're dealing with millions and millions of entries. Speed differences with only nine entries are also going to be pretty much irrelevant.

As far as optimization (for memory or time) is concerned, *feelings* aren't worth anything. You have to profile the system (several times) to see who is really chewing up memory (or if there really is noticeable memory waste at all) or wasting time. The results of profiling will usually surprise you and gurus alike, hence the admonition: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.* Always start with the most natural representation so that you can get clean, sensible, and working code: optimizing a clean and working piece of software is a lot easier than debugging a big pile of complexity that is trying to solve problems that don't exist.